# What exactly HTML formatter do?

Tags: java, html, formatting

What does a html formatter do? I have formatted one html file using the below html formatter:

http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

But when i compare the two files, i could find only one difference and that is indentation. For some project i need to parse the html file, i couldn't parse the unformatted html file with jsoup but after formatting the html jsoup is parsing the html file.
Code used for parsing:

```
public Document parseHTML(String filePath)  throws IOException{

        File inputFile = new File(filePath); 
        Document fileDoc = Jsoup.parse(inputFile, null);
        return fileDoc;
     }
```

Comment: As the name suggests it basically formats html, in most cases to be more human readable. If jsoup works with the formatted html only and there are really no differences other than whitespace and line breaks then post a question on that (or rephrase this one, especially the title)  - and don't forget to post a simple example of unformatted html that doesn't work and the formatted version that works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question

> What does a html formatter do?

is on the link you shared, on the very first line :

> Formats a HTML string/file with your desired indentation level. The
>   formatting rules are not configurable but I think it provides the user
>   with the best possible output.

So it just indent the HTML strings so that it will be considered as valid HTML strings

Answer (score 0):

Some formatters make your code so beautiful you feel like crying from pure joy, for example, http://www.dirtymarkup.com/, takes this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="450" style="border-spacing:0px;color:rgb(62,80,97);font-family:Lato,Arial,San-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:13.3333px;table-layout:fixed;background-color:transparent"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" width="81" style="padding:0px"><p style="margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:16px"><img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fHPFAzy43itIJmV5eI64vf04XagIdF6yGVf7vcMWQCfZ-stb0pWyWjbF_UvZA8mPyCnPwjWeb4ItHV4YWH3OGdTS4GZhV71czA09ggSoA-FbsWoTXdVr3Molo3RWymrznp1k=s0-d-e1-ft#https://htmlsigs.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/files/000/295/371/landscape/Monkey.jpg" alt="" border="0" height="80" width="71" style="border:0px;vertical-align:middle"></p></td><td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="" width="16" style="padding:0px;border-left-width:6px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:rgb(71,124,204)"><br></td><td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="" width="363" style="padding:0px"><div><p style="text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 10px;line-height:16px;color:rgb(33,33,33)"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="4"><span style="font-weight:bold;background-color:transparent">Moo Cow</span><br></font></p><p style="margin:0px 0px 10px;line-height:16px;color:rgb(33,33,33)"><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="4"><span style="display:inline"></span></font><span style="display:block"></span><font face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="4"><span style="display:inline">(345) 977-4334</span></font></p><p style="margin:0px 0px 10px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:16px"><span style="display:inline"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/MooCow" style="color:rgb(33,33,33);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal;background-color:transparent" target="_blank"><img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Z0nLY12pdK7xeUMB--M8IKlzAbulOc1ZXo0Am9thnzcdsfOddseTVUDrqV90uSBFs-5p-Bykh2kAQC1FkBxI34w17P9GGl7gYxR79w=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.companysig.com/images/but_linkedin_logo.png" title="LinkedIn button" alt=":inkedIn button" style="border:none"></a><font color="#000000">&nbsp; </font><a href="mailto:MooCow@ucla.edu" style="color:rgb(33,33,33);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal" target="_blank"><img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lLjmL_p2lcLcwNTeXCHq_OaY8C4EDuCt2ynWpTboZUNlS6jK7LZYVszDodowST9klsHP6bPzE6ph8f6jp2xUp5wgoWr9gTIJjv8=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.companysig.com/images/but_email_black.png" title="email" alt="email" style="border:none"></a><span style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="http://www.companysig.com/X/H/HI/show_vcard3.php/HIFKBH878391.vcf" style="color:rgb(33,33,33);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal" target="_blank"><img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/cMfYHWNyrPoDyeLFX39VL_WRboFaZUb9RxYuVaxUIpDwnEbiY4K6GLvJ_y2_iUggQtflbIcabZVjFOMjENgpSytdWgVi9yrC964=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.companysig.com/images/but_vcard_black.png" title="Vcard Save Contact" alt="Vcard Save Contact" style="border:none"></a><br></span></p></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

And gives me this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=
"border-spacing:0px;color:rgb(62,80,97);font-family:Lato,Arial,San-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:13.3333px;table-layout:fixed;background-color:transparent"
width="450">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="padding:0px" valign="top" width="81">
                <p style=
                "margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:16px">
                <img alt="" border="0" height="80" src=
                "https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/fHPFAzy43itIJmV5eI64vf04XagIdF6yGVf7vcMWQCfZ-stb0pWyWjbF_UvZA8mPyCnPwjWeb4ItHV4YWH3OGdTS4GZhV71czA09ggSoA-FbsWoTXdVr3Molo3RWymrznp1k=s0-d-e1-ft#https://htmlsigs.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/files/000/295/371/landscape/Ammar.jpg"
                style="border:0px;vertical-align:middle" width="71">
                </p>
            </td>

            <td align="left" nowrap style=
            "padding:0px;border-left-width:6px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:rgb(71,124,204)"
            valign="top" width="16"><br>
            </td>

            <td align="left" nowrap style="padding:0px" valign="middle" width=
            "363">
                <div>
                    <p style=
                    "text-align:left;margin:0px 0px 10px;line-height:16px;color:rgb(33,33,33)">
                    <span style=
                    "font-weight:bold;background-color:transparent">Moo
                    Cow</span><br>
                    </p>


                    <p style=
                    "margin:0px 0px 10px;line-height:16px;color:rgb(33,33,33)">
                    <span style="display:inline"></span><span style=
                    "display:block"></span><span style="display:inline">(345)
                    977-4334</span>
                    </p>


                    <p style=
                    "margin:0px 0px 10px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:16px">
                    <span style="display:inline"><a href=
                    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/MooCow" style=
                    "color:rgb(33,33,33);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal;background-color:transparent"
                    target="_blank"><img alt=":inkedIn button" src=
                    "https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Z0nLY12pdK7xeUMB--M8IKlzAbulOc1ZXo0Am9thnzcdsfOddseTVUDrqV90uSBFs-5p-Bykh2kAQC1FkBxI34w17P9GGl7gYxR79w=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.companysig.com/images/but_linkedin_logo.png"
                    style="border:none" title="LinkedIn button"></a>&nbsp;
                    <a href="mailto:ammardiwan@ucla.edu" style=
                    "color:rgb(33,33,33);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal"
                    target="_blank"><img alt="email" src=
                    "https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lLjmL_p2lcLcwNTeXCHq_OaY8C4EDuCt2ynWpTboZUNlS6jK7LZYVszDodowST9klsHP6bPzE6ph8f6jp2xUp5wgoWr9gTIJjv8=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.companysig.com/images/but_email_black.png"
                    style="border:none" title="email"></a><span style=
                    "color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="http://www.companysig.com/X/H/HI/show_vcard3.php/HIFKBH878391.vcf"
                    style=
                    "color:rgb(33,33,33);font-family:'Times New Roman';font-size:medium;line-height:normal"
                    target="_blank"><img alt="Vcard Save Contact" src=
                    "https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/cMfYHWNyrPoDyeLFX39VL_WRboFaZUb9RxYuVaxUIpDwnEbiY4K6GLvJ_y2_iUggQtflbIcabZVjFOMjENgpSytdWgVi9yrC964=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.companysig.com/images/but_vcard_black.png"
                    style="border:none" title=
                    "Vcard Save Contact"></a><br></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Oh yes!